# Xcode 4.3.1 - Switch to Output/Console Window shortcut

Tags: xcode, console, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Xcode 4.3.1 that will place my cursor in the Output/Console window. To be clear, I would like a quick way to place my cursor next to `(lldb)` in the Output/Console window.

Also, a keyboard shortcut to then place my cursor back in the text editor window would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that "Command + Option + ." cycles between windows that include the text editor and console.

Comment: Doesn't work on Xcode 7  Can you post the key binding name?

Answer (score 3):

"Command + Shift + C" is the default for Xcode 7.

**Edit**: Still valid in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, I am adding the shortcut for Xcode 8. Go to `View->Debug Area`, here you will see the shortcut command: `Command+Shift+Y` to switch between debug/console output window area and the editor.